# Is universal instantiation correctly applied here?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The question asks me to determine if the following arguments are valid.

$\begin{array}{rcr}
A) & \forall x \forall y K(x, y) \, \vDash \forall x K(x,x)
\\ 1. & \forall x \forall y K(x,y)
\\ 2. & \forall y K(x,y) & U.I\; 1.
\\ 3. & K(x,x) & U.I\; 2.
\\ 4. & \forall x K(x,x) & U.G\; 3.
\end{array}$

Can I use universal instantiation to introduce x in that way? Is that legal? I have yet two other problems in this question and all use binary predicates like this.

Comment: Yes, it works...

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with this kind of universal instantiation.

The only thing that you need to **avoid** is situations like: $$\forall x \exists y: R(x,y) \leadsto \exists y: R(y, y)$$
(You can take $R(x,y)$ to be $x < y$ in $\Bbb N$ to see this is false.)

This amounts to saying that the variable you substitute for $x$ must be *free* (that is, not be quantified over) in all positions where $x$ occurs.